# How to divert solids from a downward vertical pipe

Tags: mechanical-engineering, marine-engineering

I am an electronics engineer trying to build one small underwater mechanical device (about 12 cubic cm) as part of a personal automation project. I have figured out the electronics for this, but I am stuck at one mechanical problem.

I want to make a 3D printable CAD model of the device. Please tell me what kind of mechanism I need, and explain its working principles.

**Description**: Each device will have one inlet and two outlets ($o_A$ and $o_B$). The inlet is at the top and the outlets $o_A$ and $o_B$ are at the bottom. In an underwater installation, these devices would be placed vertically one below other, interconnected with 3/4 inch PVC pipe. Outlet $o_A$ of the above device will be connected with the inlet of the below device with 3/4 inch PVC pipe.  Normally, the solids falling down from the inlet should flow down vertically through the bottom outlet, $o_A$. *But occasionally the solids needs to be diverted to the other outlet, $o_B$.* How can this be done?

**Update**
I see from the comments that 'Diverter Valve' is what I was looking for. Please explain its working principles.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "diverter valve", and they are commercially available both in manual and electrically-activated forms.

Comment: I believe you looking some valving system. Look at http://www.mcmaster.com/#valves/=vtkoz0 for examples this should help you get started. Also this might help you too. http://www.valworx.com/category/electric-actuated-pvc-3-way-ball-valves-l-port-115v-240v

Comment: @DaveTweed - your comment sounds like an answer.

Comment: @dcorking: It was more of a provisionary answer, pending additional information from the OP, hopefully explaining why solids are passing through his mechanism and why it needs to be underwater.

Comment: @DaveTweed and Mahendra Gunawardena: Thank you for your suggestions. 'Diverter Valve' is what I was looking for. Since I want to make a 3D printable CAD model of the device, I am trying to understand the working principles of these diverter valves and incorporate it appropriately into my design.

Comment: @Praval As you understand your question better, please post the updates in the question (or as a new question) instead of in comments, which are temporary. I proposed an edit to the question that incorporates your latest comment.

Answer (score 3):

As [Dave Tweed](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/86/dave-tweed) mentioned, this is a simple example of a diverter valve. It allows flow to be directed to one or the other output.

[image: Diagram from valve manufacturer]

[Valve manufacturer site](https://www.ductingsystems.com/nordfab-parts-manual-diverter-valve.html)